# How might we find $\sigma$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

How does one solve a "differential equation" for $\sigma$ of the form 
$$ 
\sigma(v)w_i(v)={\partial \over \partial v_j}\left[\sigma(v)A_{ij}(v)\right]
\quad i=1,\dots,n.
$$ 
where the summation convention applies.

$w,v$ are an $n$-D vectors, $\sigma$ is a scalar function, $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix?

Perhaps there is a general solution form? References (links) for the treatment of such an equation is also appreciated.

Thank you.

Added:

In light of drak's suggestion, here is a bit more

Some thoughts:

It might be friendlier to change "variables" to $A\sigma$?

Is there a more familiar expression for the index notation ${\partial \over \partial v_j}M_{ij}(v)$ such as one in  terms of $\nabla$? It would seem to me that it is taking the divergence of each row of the matrix $M$.

***Some more thoughts:*** since the function $\sigma$ appears on both sides of the equation, it is likely that it is an exponential.

***A simplified version:*** What if we suppose that $A$ is a **constant** matrix?

Comment: Since you are a new user, here are  a few things about the site you
should know:
1. To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say where
the problem originated,
2. You will get a better response, if you indicate, what you have
already tried to answer the question yourself.

and finally: Welcome to math.SE!

Comment: @draks : Thank you, I have added something to my post.

Comment: Consider the ODE $\frac{d}{dt} p(t)u(t) = q(t)u(t)$ ($u$ is the unknown). How would you solve it? Can you always "change variables" like $v(t)=p(t)u(t)$?

Comment: @Siminore: hmm, perhaps not... but then what can I do?

Comment: @Siminore: what if we start with $A$ is a constant matrix?

Comment: If $A$ is constant, and since $\sigma$ is a real-valued function, the equation should be easier.

Comment: @Siminore: thank you, is there a general form of solution for such an equation? I suspect it is some exponential function, but i am new to matrix/vector differential equations so i don;t know how it should look like. could you please help me out?

Comment: Formally it is like the ODE case. But you need to learn the exponentiation of a matrix.

Comment: If this can help, your equation is equivalent to $$\nabla\sigma(v)=\sigma(v)A^{-1}[w(v)-B(v)]$$ where $B(v):=(\text{div}A_1(v),\ldots,\text{div}A_n(v))$ with $A_i(v)$ the $i$-th row from $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\w{{\bf w}}
\def\A{{\bf A}}
\def\B{{\bf B}}
\def\v{{\bf v}}
\def\u{{\bf u}}
\def\grad{\nabla}
\def\darg{{\overleftarrow \nabla}}
\def\t{\tau}$There is a notation used in physics that can handle these sorts of operations without indices.
The differential equation takes the form 
$$\begin{equation*}
(\A \sigma)\darg = \w \sigma,\tag{1}
\end{equation*}$$
where $(\B\darg)_{i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial v_j} B_{ij}$. 
Then 
$$(\A\darg + \A\grad)\sigma = \w\sigma,$$
so $\A\grad\sigma = (\w - \A\darg)\sigma$, or
$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sigma} \grad\sigma = \A^{-1}(\w - \A\darg).\tag{2}
\end{equation*}$$
This is the equation given by @Mercy in the comments.

A natural ansatz is $\sigma = e^\t$, since $e^{-\t}\grad e^\t = \grad \t$.
Thus, we must solve
$$\grad \t = \A^{-1}(\w - \A\darg),$$
to which we can apply the [gradient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem).
We find
$$\t(\v) - \t(\v_0) = \int_{\v_0}^{\v} d\u^T\, 
\A^{-1}(\u)\left(\w(\u) - \A(\u)\darg_\u\right).$$
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\sigma(\v) = \sigma(\v_0)\exp
\int_{\v_0}^{\v} d\u^T\, \A^{-1}(\u)\left(\w(\u) - \A(\u)\darg_\u\right).\tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Let's make sure we can unwind this expression.
It is shorthand for
$$\sigma(\v) = \sigma(\v_0) \exp
\int_{\v_0}^{\v} d u_i\,
(A^{-1}(\u))_{ij}\left(w_{j}(\u) - \frac{\partial}{\partial u_k} A_{jk}(\u)\right).$$
Note that the exponent is a scalar.
It is the line integral of the vector field
$\A^{-1}(\w - \A\darg)$.

**Special case**

Suppose $\A$ and $\w$ are constant and $\v_0 = 0$. 
The solution is then 
$$\sigma(\v) = \sigma(0) \exp \left(\v^T\A^{-1}\w\right),$$ 
which satisfies the differential equation (1) since 
$(\A \sigma)\darg = \A\grad \sigma = \A \A^{-1}\w \sigma = \w\sigma$. 
(We [choose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) the gradient to be a column vector so 
$\grad(\v^T\A^{-1}\w) = \A^{-1}\w$.)